# how to use RetryAfter Header in retryWhen in rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java

I have the below retry code when there is a exception

```
.retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>() 
{
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) {
                        return observable.zipWith(retryRange, new Func2<Throwable, Integer, Object>() {
                            @Override
                            public Object call(@Track Throwable throwable, Integer retryCount) {
                                return retryCount;
                            }
                        });
                    }
            })
```

This code keeps retrying the api call if there is an exception until the retryRange.

I need to add a check here to get the errorCode and if its 503, then I need to check the header value "retryAfter" and use that time to delay the retry.
I don't know how to get the header in the above retryWhen and use it delay the retry

Comment: You could enhance the throwable that signals the error condition with an indication that it is a 503, and add a field with the "retryAfter" value.

Comment: can I get a code snippet for it.

Comment: Define a class that extends `Exception`; add fields for the status code and retry value. In your `retryWhen()`, determine that the exception is your particular class, extracts the status code and retry value, and then uses them to make a decision.

Comment: how would I get the header, retry-after is the header of the error response

Comment: In your upstream observable, you have to inspect the response and turn it into a custom exception. You haven't shown your upstream code, so I can't comment on it.

Comment: I added flatMap after zipWith, returned the throwable and got the delay the call based on the "Retry-After" header from response

Answer (score 1):

The below solution worked for me:

```
  .retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) {
                        return observable.zipWith(retryRange, new Func2<Throwable, Integer, Object>() {
                            @Override
                            public Object call(@Track Throwable throwable, Integer attempt) {

                                return throwable;
                            }
                        }).flatMap((new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Observable<?> call(Throwable throwable) {
                                long delayTime = 0;
                                if (throwable instanceof HttpException && ((HttpException) throwable).code() == 503) {
                                    HttpException exception = (HttpException) throwable;
                                    Response response = exception.getErrorResponse();
                                    delayTime = getDelayTime(response.headers());

                                }
                                return Observable.timer(delayTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                            }
                        }));
```